# intelij multi module maven capabilities

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I've recently moved from c# .Net / Visual Studio, to Java / Maven InteliJ Idea Community.

Some things that I expect my IDE to do for me seems missing:

1. Generating a dependency graph between my modules to see which module references what dependent modules. I expected some kind of GUI or plugin for visualising these connections - but find myself going through multiple pom files manually.
2. Viewing which external dependencies are used by my app across modules and compare their versions. Being able to add an external library that is already referenced by some of my modules, to a newly created module, without the need to copy paste pom xml.
3. NUGET was used for discovery of new libraries and updates in .Net, is there an equivalent tool for that in InteliJ+Maven ?

   Thanks

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/

Comment: BTW: For external libraries, it is often a good idea to manage their versions in the parent POM (through dependencyManagement).

Comment: Still, It's XML manipulation by hand. Seems like too much manual labour, and also risky..

Comment: There is a complete comparison between ultimate (commerical) and the community edition https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html  and the diagrams are part of the ultimate license...Apart from that If I'm in a pom file I just type `Command-N` and a menu will open and show dependencies/dependencyManagement where I can choose from...no need to do  xml but of course it's possilbe and very well supported via just within the pom type `dep` and Ctrl-Space..etc.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ has similar features :

1) The IntelliJ built-in maven plugin has a feature a show dependencies icon

2) You can enable the maven auto-import for your project, IntelliJ will check unresolved dependencies for you

Comment: Thanks, I already got to work with those.
Is there a way to copy paste a dependency between modules? or compare a specific dependency across modules in one view? or even show possible upgrades?

Comment: I don't think so, I've already worked with VS, it's very sophisticated. On other hand, so still do a lot of things manually. For dependencies, you can see all imported versions for a specific  dependency on the IntelliJ dependency graph. An other thing IntelliJ also support plugins, maybe there one that can handle that, let's me know if so.